# Too many arguments to function call, expected single argument 'combinedValues', have 2 arguments

Tags: c, function, return

Sorry for using the incorrect jargon and so on, I've just started learning how to program this week. Anyway, in the book I'm using there is a challenge:

> The interior angles of a triangle must add up to 180 degrees. Create a new C Command Line Tool named Triangle. In main.c, write a function that takes the first two angles and returns the third. Here's what it will look like when you call it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Add your new function here

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
float angleA = 30.0;
float angleB = 60.0;
float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA, angleB);
printf("The third angle is %.2f\n", angleC);
return 0;
}
```

So far I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Declare a global variable?
float totalNumbers;

float remainingAngle(float combinedValues) // One argument here
{
totalNumbers = combinedValues;
float remainingAngle = combinedValues * 30.0 + 60.0;
return remainingAngle;
}

// Add new function here

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
float angleA = 30.0;
float angleB = 60.0;
float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA, angleB); // Two arguments here
//Above line is giving me the error, see explanation below
printf("The third angle is %.2f\n", angleC);
return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the error (on line that starts out float angleC = remainingAngle... it's 4th from the bottom in my code)

> Too many arguments to function call, expected single argument 'combinedValues', have 2 arguments

So, can you guys tell me how to fix my code? I am a complete beginner and just ask that you at least tell me how to rephrase the question/etc to get help if I've broken any unwritten rules. Thank you.

Comment: You declared the remainingAngle function with one argument, but then you tried to call it with two arguments.  I've added two comments to your code pointing out the differences.

Comment: @Robert Harvey do you think it is smart to edit the solution in to the question? this lets look the poster look like a fool and could also confuse people what exactly the question was about, don't you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe how the function is called

```
float angleC = remainingAngle(angleA, angleB);
```

It takes two arguments (inputs), does something with them and returns one output which is assigned back to `angleC`. So you need to code accordingly

```
float remainingAngle(float angleA, float angleB) //accepts two `float` arguments and returns `float` value
{
    float angleC;

    //sum of all angles is 180. So third angle is 180 - (sum of other two)
    angleC = 180 - (angleA+angleB);
    return angleC;
}
```